# How to use bit shifting for modulus?

Tags: java, optimization

I have just started  to use bit shifting to optimize some of my code for SPOJ programming problems.  I am looking for how to do this with modulus.  Does anyone have any suggestions or links to information that could be of any help?

Comment: Did you profile to check this micro-optimization was effective and wasn't already done for you by the compiler or JIT ?

Comment: My suggestion is - Micro-optimizations won't get you anywhere significant. If your program is taking too long, you need a completely different algorithm.

Comment: If you feel like trying to outperform JIT, try this (C, but easily translatable to Java): http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ModulusDivisionEasy

Comment: Try changing your algorithms first.

Comment: @dystroy The code is compiled by the SPOJ server and is not added into the program.  I need a way to shave off .01s and this might be a helpful option.

Comment: btw, it's interesting how SPOJ accounts for long JVM start-up, JIT delays and GC. Looks like it's better to use C there... Or do they use some native Java compiler, like `gcj`? Even if they do, there's still GC pauses...

Comment: @victor-sorokin Thank you for the link and the advice. Would you recommend doing the problems in C?

Comment: I can't recommend, I didn't do it myself. Instead, it would be interesting to hear about your experience with Java on SPOJ. For example, have you been able to reach execution times of C programs with your Java versions?

Comment: I have not tried programming any problems in C yet.  I will try to use the same algorithm with C an see if it works with in the acceptable time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to use bit shifting for a modulus operation. Bit shifting is more akin to division than modulus.

Bitwise AND can be used for some very simple modulus operations (e.g, `& 3` instead of `% 4`), but the speedup is pretty minimal, and an optimizing JRE is likely to make that optimization on its own already.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this isn't insultingly basic, but bit-masking (not really bit-shifting) for modulus will only work for divisors that are powers of 2. So the bit-masking technique tends to be useful only in a subset of situations in which you know in advance what the divisor will be.

Also, if you can hardcode the divisor--that's usually a case where the compiler will optimize the calculation as well as you can anyway.